# Using Win32 ReadFile and malloc

Tags: malloc, readfile

My dynamically allocated variable is trimmed with SecureZeroMemory, then ReadFile populates it with a short 5char string and a bunch of remaining squares. The problem is the junk characters at the end of the string:

"motor췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍"

The ReadFile's lpNumberOfBytesRead parameter shows the string is 10chars, prbly because it's Unicode?

Can someone help show me how to remove these trailing junk characters? Is there a function like ZeroMemory that clears them?

```
TCHAR *sIncoming;
sIncoming = (TCHAR *) malloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * 4096 +  sizeof(TCHAR));
RtlZeroMemory(sIncoming ,sizeof(sIncoming));

// (a string array with no characters in it: "")

bSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe,sIncoming ,BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),&dwBytesRead,NULL);

// Now the string array has the incoming string plus extra characters in it: 
//    "motor췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍췍"

free(sIncoming);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use BUFSIZE also in the call to malloc, not just in the one to ReadFile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero-terminate (after the *successful* call to `ReadFile` of course):

```
sIncoming[dwBytesRead/sizeof(TCHAR)] = 0;
```

NB: observe the buffer limits.

Complete spliced into your code:

```
#define BUFSIZE 4096
TCHAR *sIncoming;
sIncoming = (TCHAR *) malloc(sizeof(TCHAR)*BUFSIZE+sizeof(TCHAR));
bSuccess = ReadFile(hPipe,sIncoming ,BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),&dwBytesRead,NULL);
if(bSuccess)
  sIncoming[dwBytesRead/sizeof(TCHAR)] = 0;
free(sIncoming);
```

Edit: Removed the `RtlZeroMemory` call as it is not strictly necessary. Just be sure to zero-terminate the received C-string.

Comment: OK! Thanks!
Or remove RtlZeroMemory and put in calloc per Erik?

Comment: @JeffR: yes, the RtlZeroMemory is not necessary. Whether malloc or calloc is only a matter of taste - it's cosmetic. Important is that C strings are zero-terminated. What you receive is apparently not. Thus you have to take care of that.

Comment: @JeffR: I removed the `RtlZeroMemory` call from my answer.

Comment: What if the incoming string is null-terminated? Will doing the sIncoming[dwBytesRead/sizeof(TCHAR)] = 0; cause any problems?

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(sIncoming) is the size of a pointer. You want sizeof(TCHAR) * 4097. Or just use calloc.

Comment: sizeof(TCHAR) * 4096 +  sizeof(TCHAR) == sizeof(TCHAR)*4097

Comment: Actually `sizeof(TCHAR) * BUFSIZE` ... if the allocation is one character more to hold the terminating zero. The idea in the code is that we allocate space for one character more in the buffer than we request from the pipe.

Comment: Didn't use BUFSIZE since it's not shown to be correct in OPs post. But yes, a *correct* constant would be better

Comment: So:

 TCHAR *sIncoming;
 sIncoming= (TCHAR *) calloc(sizeof(TCHAR) * BUFSIZE + sizeof(TCHAR));
 ReadFile(hPipe,sProdID,BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),&dwBytesRead,NULL);
 sProdID[dwBytesRead/sizeof(TCHAR)] = 0;

?

Comment: Then use `(BUFSIZE + 1)*sizeof(TCHAR)`, or just zero-terminate like STATUS suggested

Comment: no, calloc is used like this: `calloc(BUFSIZE+1, sizeof(TCHAR));` - allocate and clear `BUFSIZE+1` elements of size `sizeof(TCHAR)`

Comment: Ok, great. Q: does it matter if BUFSIZE is 4096 or 256 when it comes to speed of allocation of memory? This ReadFile is from a Named Pipe.

Comment: You won't notice the difference, if there's any :) - The IO will take a lot more time than clearing a few K of memory.